# Kubernetes Elasticsearch centos - unable to start nginx in the pod

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, kubernetes

I am using elasticsearch in kubernetes. I wish to add another layer of protection using nginx.

When I try to run nginx using `systemctl start nginx` I get:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

This seems to be a known problem with `centos` because its docker distribution does not come with a full `systemd`.

Following the centos guide for this did not work for me:

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos see section `Dockerfile for systemd base image`

**My Tries**

Docker file -

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1


ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

# Install gcs plugin
RUN bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch repository-gcs

# install nginx
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum install -y nginx

# Copy configuration
COPY my-config.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-config.conf


CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Also tried to add docker arguments in the kubernetes yaml -

```
args:
  ["--tmpfs", "/run", "-v", "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"]
```

or

```
["-ti", "-v", "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro", "-v", "/tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run"]
```

None of these helped.

Seen many answers about this issue but none seem to work, for example:
https://serverfault.com/questions/824975/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted
https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/45#issuecomment-363709254

Using priviliged docker container is not recomended for safty reasons so i rather not use it.

How can i make this work?

Comment: You'd almost always run Nginx in a totally separate pod.  For Elasticsearch in particular, what benefits are you hoping to get by adding the Nginx proxy; you'd almost never make your database directly accessible from outside the cluster?

Comment: The elastic will be only available inside the cluster. I want to add client certificate, allow access to some of the endpoints(e.g specific indexes). Is using nginx in a seperate pod is the best practice for that case? It means every request will be sent to nginx and then forwarded to elastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are built to run a single application. You should use a separate one for the nginx proxy and another for Elasticsearch.